# Do local reports have any drawbacks in comparison with remote reports?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

We have a project that needs reporting capabilities, but the backing database is Oracle (this is hard requirement), and if it is possible I'd like to avoid having to purchase SQL Server for the deployment environment.

Our experience thus far has been to develop deploy reports in SSRS, but now it seems we will have to use local reports. I'd like to know whether there are any functional drawbacks in local reports vs remote reports (SSRS).

Some of the requirements we have are:

- Ability to export in excel and pdf
- Drill-through capabilities
- Charts

My [current research](http://ensoftinc.wordpress.com/2009/10/02/reporting-services-2005-local-vs-remote-reports/) says that there aren't any functional drawbacks to using local reports, but the article talks is about sql server 2005, and we are using VS 2008. Is this true? Are there going to be any other functional problems ahead?

Comment: This is purely anecdotal but recalling a conversation with an acquaintance who, is extremely familiar with SSRS and its inner workings, made the point in the past that there are hardly any differences between 2005 and 2008.

Comment: @SeanCocteau There were bigger changes in SSRS 2008 than any other releases so far. SSRS 2008 did away with IIS on the server side, implemented the tablix model for reports, charts and Gauges from Dundas, &c. &c. This doesn't have much bearing on the OP question, but more than a few differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even no one answered this question, I wanted to leave the feedback for possible future inquiries.

We implemented the project using RDLC reports and mostly things worked fine. Graphs, drill throughs, matrices etc.

Two major differences are to be noted:

1. No filter parameters are generated for you. Reporting services places a strip of customizable filters on top of the report. For RDLC reports you have to build these filters manually.
2. Data sources are a little harder to work with. Most problems we had was because or backend database was oracle and the entity wrapper had some issues with figuring out the return schemas of procedures. So, we used views instead.